# disable js script with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

in one page function i want disable js script.

How make that?

I try jquery: hide(), but this not' work

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "disable js script"?
You want no javascript in that page? Then don't write javascript at all.

This "one page" is part of your site (or the site/web app you are developing) right?

JQuery [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is for a completely different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable JS as it is a client side controlled setting. the only option is to not have any javascript on that page.